# AcquireNextFrame customize dimension

Tags: c++, directx, screenshot, screen-capture, dxgi

I'm using `AcquireNextFrame` to make a screenshot of my desktop. Is it possible to set a dimension of the image I want.
For example : default resolution of my computer is 1920x1080 and I would like to get the image in 1280x720.
I call this function many times so if it's possible to set a dimension before it would be great.

Here is my code :

```
HRESULT hr;
hr = gDevice->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&gDxgiDevice));
hr = gDxgiDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&gDxgiAdapter));
gDxgiDevice->Release();
UINT Output = 0;
IDXGIOutput *lDxgiOutput = nullptr;
hr = gDxgiAdapter->EnumOutputs(Output, &lDxgiOutput);
gDxgiAdapter->Release();
hr = lDxgiOutput->GetDesc(&gOutputDesc);
IDXGIOutput1 *lDxgiOutput1 = nullptr;
hr = lDxgiOutput->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&lDxgiOutput1));
lDxgiOutput->Release();
hr = lDxgiOutput1->DuplicateOutput(gDevice, &gDeskDupl);
lDxgiOutput1->Release();
gDeskDupl->GetDesc(&gOutputDuplDesc);
hr = gDeskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(100, &frameInfo, &desktopResource);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This apparently duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325283/custom-output-resolution-duplicateoutput-dxgi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom output resolution DuplicateOutput DXGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325283/custom-output-resolution-duplicateoutput-dxgi)