# Custom output resolution DuplicateOutput DXGI

Tags: c++, directx, screenshot, screen-capture, dxgi

I'm using `AcquireNextFrame` to make a screenshot of my desktop. Is it possible to set a dimension of the output image I want on the setup ?
I saw on the documentation this function `IDXGIOutput::SetDisplaySurface` that could help.
Here is my code :

```
//Here I init a output texture with less resolution 
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    desc.Width = 1280;
    desc.Height = 720;
    desc.MipLevels = desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    desc.BindFlags = 0;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;

    ID3D11Texture2D *pTexture = NULL;
    gDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, NULL, &pTexture);
    IDXGISurface *surface = nullptr;
    hr = gDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGISurface), reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pTexture));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return;
    // Here I should make lDxgiOutput->setDisplaySurface(surface)
    hr = lDxgiOutput->GetDesc(&gOutputDesc);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return;
    IDXGIOutput1 *lDxgiOutput1 = nullptr;
    hr = lDxgiOutput->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&lDxgiOutput1));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return;
    lDxgiOutput->Release();
    hr = lDxgiOutput1->DuplicateOutput(gDevice, &gDeskDupl);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return;
```

My screen is 1920x1080 and I would like to get image in 1280x720 for example.
I'm getting an error on `queryinterface` function. 
Can someone tell me what I'm missing ? Or is there any solution to customize the resolution easier ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop Duplication API gets you a copy of desktop as a texture with least overhead. That is, no scaling is included. You can grab frames and scale them down as you wish, but this is not what Desktop Duplication does or expected to do for you.

This question suggests a few ways (and the question is also related to Desktop Duplication):

- [Resizing a DXGI Resource or Texture2D in SharpDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064837/resizing-a-dxgi-resource-or-texture2d-in-sharpdx)

Additionally, you can use Media Foundation's [Video Processor MFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162913), which is somewhat inflexible and has a possibly inconvenient form factor if you don't use Media Foundation otherwise, but properly set up scales using Direct3D 11 in efficient way performance-wise.

See also on another related API for GPU-enabled scaling:

- [DXVA Video Processing - Example 7: Stretching and Cropping Video](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307964#example_7__stretching_and_cropping_video)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is that with AcquireNextFrame I'm getting the DirtyRect and MoveRect. And I'm getting it from the desktop initial resolution. So if I scale the texture2D, the Dirty & Move Rect will not be synchronize with the new scaled Texture... That's the big problem. That's why I was asking for an output scaled already... Too bad that Microsoft did not think about that...

Comment: If you scale the texture, you can scale the rectangles respectively, can't you? Desktop Duplication gives you sufficient input, you have all you need to process the data further.

Comment: Yes that's true.. I have to do the right calculation. Not impossible.
To tell you the truth, I still have not succeeded to simply scale the texture... should I use SharpDX ? There is no tutorial showing the steps to do this correctly..

Comment: I, for once, used Video Processor MFT and I know it works well. I don't have sample code to refer to though. I suppose Direct2D can work decently too. I linked he question which explains steps for Direct2D scaling. DXVA link is mostly for completeness, I don't think you should take this path due to complexity.